# nc -l not working on using public IP address

Tags: ip, client-server, netcat

When i try to use [nc -l] command with my private IP address,i am able to create a client server model.But it doesn't work when i try to use my public IP address with the same port number.It gives me the following error:-
nc: Can't assign requested address
Why??

Comment: Is your PC connected to the internet using a router? If so, are you trying to bind to the IP visible to the internet? That one is the IP address of your router, not of your PC. So you can't bind to it, unless you execute the code on your router.

Comment: So, I am connected to a router and if i google what my public ip address is, the IP address that i get is of my router and not of my system. Correct me if i am wrong @andreas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your public IP is the IP of your router, not your computer.

Simplified, your network probably looks like this (IP addresses are only examples):

```
+--------------+     +-----------------+----------------+
| PC           |-----|Router (internal)|Router(external)|---... Internet
| 192.168.0.10 |     |192.168.0.1      |123.132.122.133 |
+--------------+     +-----------------+----------------+
```

Your PC's internal address is `192.168.0.10`, and that's the only address it knows. The router routes traffic to other networks; for that it has two interfaces, the internal one with the address `192.168.0.1` and the internet-facing one (`123.132.122.133`). On your PC, you can't listen on the latter address, since that's the *router*'s address, not the one of the *PC*.

So the solution is to listen on the internal IP, and setup the router to forward traffic of the respective port to the corresponding port on your PC. Beware of the security implications, though! (E.g. leaving a root shell open to the internet might not be the best idea.)